# DotNetNuke: Conditional logic for displaying menu items

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am new to DotNetNuke, but I'm an experienced web admin and programmer.

I have an ASP .NET website / web application that I want to integrate into DNN 5 so I can easily add / modify content, etc. My existing site uses it's own login system to display user information. I have successfully placed (using iframes) all of my existing pages inside DNN pages.

The problem I am having is that I need to conditionally hide certain pages in the menu until a user is logged into my application. To be clear, my users are logging in using my existing authentication system, and will not actually login to DNN, so I can't simply grant permissions to those pages.

My question is this: is there some way (perhaps by modifying the DNN code) to conditionally hide menu items until certain requirements are met, such as authentication through my login system?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own DNN Authentication module that leverages your current system and code.

Our shop uses DNN, but hands off authentication to our university's centralized authentication system. I didn't write it, but I don't get the impression that it was too hard. Now when we create a portal, we install and enable our authentication module and then turn off DNN Authentication. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

We used DNN Garden menu for this (we do some thing sort of like that) the menu has a Node manipulator interface you can code against

http://www.dnngarden.com/

http://www.dnngarden.com/Menu-structure-manipulation.T104.aspx

- we have had great success with this -

The other option which we have done as well is to write your own menu provider - not really that hard